# Java annotation and code execution at runtime

Tags: java, annotations

Annotations supposedly are markers/provide metadata, so for example how does the `@RolesAllowed` annotation in JAX-RS work? This annotation "executes" code since it checks that the user is authenticated and has the required roles, at runtime (when an annotated method is called).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is code that checks if the annotation exists and performs operations based on it. The annotation itself just lies there. The code that performs the checking and operations is executed around the method call.

Comment: Using AOP or something?

Comment: Indeedio. Technically it doesn't need to be AOP, but that allows it to be used in a general fashion, instead of requiring special code constructs.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks. My question can be deleted now ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not quite that powerful.